# Python задача с использованием времени

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужна помощь в решении одной задачи,  есть персона - скажем что он ложится после 00:00. Нам нужна програма которая бы выпрашивала у нас время когда он ложится спать через тот же int(input()) и время когда он проснётся. Допустим он ложится в 3 часа 35 минут и спит он ровно 2 часа и 45 минут выходит что он просыпается в 6 утра 30 минут так вот у меня вопрос как же конвертировать 5 часов 80 минут в 6 часов и 30 минут?

Comment: Вообще-то исходя из ваших данных либо он должен просыпаться в 6:20, либо он спит 2:55, либо он ложится в 3:45. Какое-то время у вас неправильное, не сходятся подсчёты.

Comment: А как вы в быту прибавляете 2:45 к 3:35?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще ваше решение костылем попахивает, вам не обязательно получать 5 часов 80 минут для решения этой задачи, но, если хотите:

```
def Func():
    hoursStart = int(input("В какой час вы ложитесь спать: ?"))
    minutesStart = int(input("Во сколько минут в этом часу вы ложитесь спать?"))

    hoursEnd = int(input("Сколько часов вы хотете поспать?"))
    minutesEnd = int(input("Сколько минут вы хотите поспать(в плюс к часам)?"))

    if (minutesStart > 59 or minutesEnd >59):
        hours = "<<Ошибка!>>"
        minutes = "<<Попытка указать больше 59-ти минут. Воспользуйтесь полем для часов если вам нужно больше 59 минут. Давайте попробуем еще раз.>>"
        return hours, minutes
    else:
        hours =  hoursStart + hoursEnd
        minutes = minutesStart + minutesEnd
        if minutes > 59:
            minutes = minutes - 60
            hours += 1
        return hours, minutes

hours, minutes = Func()
print("Вы проснетесь в ", hours," часов ", minutes, " минут")
```

Но не забудьте тогда еще по аналогии решить проблему с часами/сутками (если, например, человек ложится спать в 23:00 и спит 15 часов, то что тогда?) А вообще, посмотрите в сторону библиотеки datetime, особое внимание советую обратить на ее метод timedelta.

https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

Проще все перевести в минуты, считать в минутах, потом результат уже перевести в часы и минуты (поделить с остатком на 60).

Пример:

```
hours_start = 3
minutes_start = 35
start = hours_start * 60 + minutes_start  # Начало переводим в минуты

hours_duration = 2
minutes_duration = 45
duration = hours_duration * 60 + minutes_duration  # Длительность переводим в минуты

end = start + duration  # Просто сложением получаем конец периода в минутах

# divmod возвращает пару значений - результат целочисленного деления и остаток от деления
# В нашем случае - это часы и минуты
hours_end, minutes_end = divmod(end, 60)  
print(hours_end, minutes_end)  # Вывод: 6 20 (т.е. 6 часов 20 минут)
```

"Настоящие" модули для работы с датой и временем (тот же datetime) работают похожим образом, только используют не минуты в качестве минимальной единицы, а секунды.